# python3 UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I am having some issues running my program. I have a "masterfile" that has a list of ips on a \n like so but I keep getting this error message:

```
68.x.0.56
68.x.0.53
```

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is, but I've been searching forums and other stackoverflow help, but can't seem to determine what the issue is.

```
def dns_resolver(subdomains):
    print('\n\n########## Checking Subdomains for DNS Resolutions ##########\n')
    queries = []
    with open ('masterfile', 'r') as f:
        domains = f.read().splitlines()
        for i in domains:
            try:
                resp = socket.gethostbyname(i)
                print(resp)
                queries.append((i, resp))
            except socket.error:
                pass
    return queries
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/idna.py", line 165, in encode
    raise UnicodeError("label empty or too long")
UnicodeError: label empty or too long

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subdomain-hunter.py", line 170, in <module>
    main()
  File "subdomain-hunter.py", line 59, in main
    enumerate(DOMAIN)
  File "subdomain-hunter.py", line 120, in enumerate
    resolvediff = dns_resolver(diff)
  File "subdomain-hunter.py", line 142, in dns_resolver
    resp = socket.gethostbyname(i)
UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` when this happens?